# How to do Keypress Validation in a Delphi 7 Console Application

Tags: delphi

I am creating a simple delphi console app which does arithmetic operations of the number entered by user, problem is that the user can enter 'a'..'z','A'..'Z' which leads to app crash. How can i prevent this? Using try-except does not work, anybody has ideas on preventing this crash?

Here is my code:

```
 Write('Please Enter a Number:=');
Readln(str1);
try
  num1:=StrToFloat(str1);
except
on e:exception do
  Writeln(e.message);
end;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: exception handling works fine in console apps - there must be something that you are not telling us

Comment: what have i got to hide David? num1 is of type Double.

Comment: What do you mean by "leads to app crash"?

Comment: @sunandan: You do know that if you run a console application from the IDE or by double-clicking the EXE file icon or by any other means that *create a new console window*, the console window will close as soon as your program is completed (that is, as soon as you hit the `end.`). Thus, it is hard to read the output. To remedy this, start the program from an existing console window (Win+R, `cmd`, Enter) [in Windows Vista+: Win, `cmd`, Enter], or add a `Readln` at the end of your program. That way the program will not reach the end until you press Enter.

Comment: If you create an empty VCL program with a single form, and run it, it will run indefinitely. This is because it has a message loop that runs forever (if you do nothing). A console application, however, exits (the process is terminated) as soon as the code between `begin` and `end.` is done. And if a console window was created for the program, this closes too. Hence, in most cases, you have no chance reading the output if you just F9 from the IDE and you have no `sleep` or `Readln` just before `end.`.

Comment: So, all in all, my hypothesis is that you, due to lack of knowledge of how console applications work, incorrectly say that the application 'crashes' when it simply is just done executing. In such a case, you could have realised this by yourself by creating an empty console application that simply consists of `Writeln('Hello World!')`, which you would have found to 'crash' in the same way. This technique is called 'debugging'! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David, points out, exceptions work just as fine in console apps as they do in GUI apps. For instance, this works flawlessly:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  s: string;
  f1, f2: extended;

begin

  try

    Writeln('Please enter a number:');
    Readln(s);
    f1 := StrToFloat(s);

    Writeln('Please enter a second number:');
    Readln(s);
    f2 := StrToFloat(s);

    Writeln('The sum is ', FloatToStr(f1+f2));
    Readln;

  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.Message);
      Readln;
    end;
  end;

end.
```

An alternative not using exceptions is to use the `TryStrToFloat` function:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  s1, s2: string;
  f1, f2: extended;

begin

  Writeln('Please enter a number:');
  Readln(s1);
  Writeln('Please enter a second number:');
  Readln(s2);

  if TryStrToFloat(s1, f1) and TryStrToFloat(s2, f2) then
    Writeln('The sum is ', FloatToStr(f1 + f2))
  else
    Writeln('Invalid input.');

  Readln;

end.
```